# PHP makes request from wrong ip

Tags: php, ip

i'm using opencart on a virtual host with a dedicated ip. bank allows virtual pos queries only from dedicated ip, but server ip is used by php to communicate with bank's api. is there any way to force php to use that dedicated ip?

ps: there is a [in-code solutio](http://ejth.dk/2011/php-changing-ip-for-file_get_contents/72)n, however i prefer more general solution like as php.ini edits.

Comment: Seems to me that the more general solution would be not in `php.ini` but in your network config.

Comment: What operating system is this running on?

Comment: @grossvogel nope, in my view, php binds 0.0.0.0 ip address so that
the packet exit through default gateway's way, that is the interface primary ip. however my dedicated ip as a alias ip

Comment: if you have the rights to change the routing table or your host, you could probably add a host route to the target server using the right network interface. something like `route add -host <target_ip> dev ethX`...

Comment: @bmogz: I guess I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to override the default gateway.

Comment: @brnogz:google says you can fiddle with things in  /etc/sysconfig/network and get it working that way.  Please update the question with the contents of this file.  Specifically, the entry for your desired primary interface should include the line `defroute=yes`.

Answer (score 0):

The *proper* way is to `bind()` your connecting socket to the IP address of the interface you wish to use.  This will guarantee the behavior you want.  (You can set the port number to zero to have the OS choose one.)

You can also make the OS pick the interface appropriately.  In fact, I'm surprised it is not.  You didn't list any specific IP addresses, interface configurations, or a routing table, but if we assume your private IP is 172.16.0.222 and the bank's IP address is 172.16.0.11, then opening a connecting socket to 172.16.0.11 *should* use your local private IP address.  If it's choosing your public address, then the OS thinks it has a route from that address to the destination.  Make sure that is *not* the case and your problem should be fixed.